# How we can give type to react element using TSX

Tags: reactjs, types

just want to give type to  while i convert the file from js to tsx

`export const BackNavigationTextWrapper = (WrappedComponent:type i need to specify) => {`

When i console the WrappedComponent getting like these

````
   var wrappedComponentRef = props.wrappedComponentRef,
       remainingProps = _objectWithoutProperties(props, ["wrappedComponentRef"]);

   return _react2.default.createElement(_Route… ```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the answer

without type (HOC)

```
const withLoading = Component =>
  class WithLoading extends React.Component {
    render() {
      const { loading, ...props } = this.props;
      return loading ? <LoadingSpinner /> : <Component {...props} />;
    }
  }
```

With Type

```
interface WithLoadingProps {
  loading: boolean;
}

const withLoading = <P extends object>(Component: React.ComponentType<P>) =>
  class WithLoading extends React.Component<P & WithLoadingProps> {
    render() {
      const { loading, ...props } = this.props;
      return loading ? <LoadingSpinner /> : <Component {...props as P} />;
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

As i am reading your question, i think i dont fully understand it. You want to give a React element a type, correct?

Like so?

```
export const BackNavigationTextWrapper = (componentVariable:WrappedComponent) => ..
```

otherwise please explain a little further on what you want to achieve.

Comment: yes,you are correct.. but i need to give type for wrappedComponent

export const BackNavigationTextWrapper = (WrappedComponent: <which type i need to write>) => {

Comment: this is my code
```export const BackNavigationTextWrapper = (WrappedComponent) => {
  const BackNavigationTextWrappedComponent = (props: SubPageHeaderProps) => {
    return <WrappedComponent {...props} backLabel={props.backLabel || 'Go back to reservation details'} />;
  };
  BackNavigationTextWrappedComponent.type = WrappedComponent.type;

  return BackNavigationTextWrappedComponent;
}; ```
For first line i am having doubt..what is the type i need to give for wrappedElement

Comment: Well, i am just a beginner with React so i dont actually knoow the right answer. But if you normally wouldnt need a specific type for the component, but typescript wants you to use one: did you try it with :any - just so the compiler is happy?

otherwise, from the code you provided, i am not able to identify the needed type. There will be some more advanced stackoverflowers soon :)

Comment: Hey you are right.. we can give any.. but i dont want to give any ,need to know the exact thing... yeah hoping to get more answers.